# Parsing big string (HTML code)

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm looking to parse some information on my application.
Let's say we have somewhere in that string:

```
<tr class="tablelist_bg1">

<td>Beja</td>

<td class="text_center">---</td>

<td class="text_center">19.1</td>

<td class="text_center">10.8</td>

<td class="text_center">NW</td>

<td class="text_center">50.9</td>

<td class="text_center">0</td>

<td class="text_center">1016.6</td>

<td class="text_center">---</td>

<td class="text_center">---</td>

</tr>
```

All rest that's above or below this doesn't matter. Remember this is all inside a string.
I want to get the values inside the td tags: ---, 19.1, 10.8, etc.
Worth knowing that there are many entries like this on the page.
Probably also a good idea to [link the page here](http://www.meteo.pt/pt/html.jsp).

As you probably guessed I have absolutely no idea how to do this... none of the functions I know I can perform over the string (split etc.) help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Waiting for the ones that suggest RegEx

Comment: @JustSid What else would you use that would make it easy. You could also use jquery to get the values as well and do what you need to do. I guess it really just depends on what hes trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use String.IndexOf(string, int) to find a "<td", again to find the next ">", and again to find "</td>".  Then use String.Substring to pull out a value.  Put this in a loop.

```
    public static List<string> ParseTds(string input)
    {
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        int index = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            string next = ParseTd(input, ref index);

            if (next == null)
                return results;

            results.Add(next);
        }
    }

    private static string ParseTd(string input, ref int index)
    {
        int tdIndex = input.IndexOf("<td", index);
        if (tdIndex == -1)
            return null;
        int gtIndex = input.IndexOf(">", tdIndex);
        if (gtIndex == -1)
            return null;
        int endIndex = input.IndexOf("</td>", gtIndex);
        if (endIndex == -1)
            return null;

        index = endIndex;

        return input.Substring(gtIndex + 1, endIndex - gtIndex - 1);
    }
```

Comment: A very nice answer and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is valid XHTML, you can use use an XML parser to get the content you want. There's a [simple example here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) that shows how to use `XmlTextReader` to parse XML content. The example reads from a file, but you can change it to read from a string:

```
new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(someString));
```

You specifically want to keep track of `td` element nodes, and the text node that follows them will contain the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a loop to load each non empty line from the file into a String
- Process the string character by character

  - Check for characters indicating the the begining of a td tag
  - use a substring function or just bulild a new string character by character to get all the content until the `</td>` tag begins.